# How to remove files downloaded from CS:GO Online browser game?

Tags: graphics

I played CS:GO online in Google Chrome. When I started to play, I think it downloaded a lot of files. It was the first donwload and it took some time to download. It downloaded files of about 300 Mb. Now I want to delete these files, as I am not going to play CS:GO on this pc again.

Please tell where are these files downloaded? I searched a lot but couldn`t find any files.

Comment: They should be in the browser cache.

Comment: Thanks. Clearing cache worked.

Comment: I made it an answer so you can do the up arrow for the rep thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the files from the cache should take care of it.